# python exclude directories

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

I recently wrote a small code to read directories. What i would like to do is to exclude some of them.

```
import os

exclude_prefixes = ['$RECYCLE.BIN']
src = raw_input("Enter source disk location: ")
src = os.path.dirname(src) 
for dir,_,_ in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
    dir[:] = [d for d in dir if d not in exclude_prefixes]
```

When i tried to execute this code I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\programs\MdiAdmin.py", line 40, in <module>
    dir[:] = [d for d in dir if d not in exclude_prefixes]
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

How do I fix that ?

Comment: `dir` is a (unicode) string, what are you trying to do with the list comprehension?

Comment: I would like to read all subdirectories (except those , stored in '$RECYCLE.BIN' ) and move them if they contain txt file, : file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.txt")) 

    for file in file_path: 
        f = open(file, 'r')
        object_name = f.readlines()
        f.close()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning to the wrong thing. You need to edit the `dirs` array in top-down mode, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.walk#os.walk:

> If optional argument `topdown` is `True` or not specified, the triple for a directory is generated before the triples for any of its subdirectories (directories are generated top-down). If `topdown` is `False`, the triple for a directory is generated after the triples for all of its subdirectories (directories are generated bottom-up). No matter the value of `topdown`, the list of subdirectories is retrieved before the tuples for the directory and its subdirectories are generated.
>
> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform `walk()` about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes `walk()` again. Modifying `dirnames` when `topdown` is `False` has no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the directories in `dirnames` are generated before `dirpath` itself is generated.

So you probably want something like:

```
for dir, dirs, _ in os.walk(src, topdown=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_prefixes]
```